# How to make a XML or JSon configuration file and deserialize it in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript

We are building our website using Dojo javascript only. For some functionalities, we want to use config files to populate some properties and list items during run time. I know how to Deserialize the XML file in C# server side code, but can I do the same thing in Javascript? Is there any examples that I can reference?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: Do you mean turning a JSON string into a JSON object? If not, what's there to deserialize? It will already be an object.

Comment: For example, I make a self-defined XML file to help me populate my PieChart Widget at runtime, and I need to deserialize it in javascript. <PieChartWidgetConfig >
  <PieChartItems >    
    <PieChart  Type="intersected" Title="Ecology" LegendTitle="Surveyed,To be surveyed">
      <Layers>
        <Layer ServiceName="Enbridge Layers" lyrName="Wetland" Where="" />
        <Layer ServiceName="Enbridge Layers" lyrName="Route " Where="" />
      </Layers>
    </PieChart>
  </PieChartItems>
</PieChartWidgetConfig>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for Dojo.fromJson:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fromJson.html#dojo-fromjson

If you get th JSON String in JavaScript, you can just use that function to turn it into objects.

Also, eval() is generally discouraged. [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's eval() method